# Copy value from Row and column corresponding to all X'es in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task where i have "Function" in column A,  and tags in rows with "X" in middle showing which tag and function is connected together (Please see attachment)

I have been trying to make a script that can go to the "Function (Column A)", check if it will find Value "X" in the same row, if it finds it will go up and get the tag posting the information in new sheet.

Sheet2 will then be showing:

Function -> and thich Tag is in the same function, if there is few tags like in the example below it will show like this.

### 802AB Tag1

### 802AB Tag2

### 802AB Tag3

### 802AB Tag4

### 802AB Tag5

### 804AB Tag4

### 805AB Tag2

I have few hundrets of those files, which are very big so this is simplified example. Thank you for your help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMg0C.jpg

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim writeRow As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lColor, ColorRow As Long
Dim rColored As Range
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim temprow As Long
Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long

lColor = RGB(255, 153, 204)
Set rColored = Nothing

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
writeRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:A" & lastRow)

For Each cel In rng
  If cel.Interior.Color = lColor Then
    ColorRow = cel.Row + 1

    For j = ColorRow + 1 To lastRow

        For i = ColorRow + 1 To lastRow

        lnCol = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="X", 
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlBycolumn, 
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
   '   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & writeRow).Value = cel.Offset(0, 0).Value
     '   writeRow = writeRow + 1
        Next i

    Next j
    'End If

        If rColored Is Nothing Then

        Else
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & writeRow).Value = cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            writeRow = writeRow + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

This is basically what i have, not yet functional, it searches for the first row with the right format color, then it starts a loop going through rows, searches for X in row, and it stops, I need Copy the tag where it found row, and go to the next X in same row, after all rows is done it shall go to next row do the same.

Comment: Please post your coding efforts and describe specific problems you have.

Comment: The code i have did never work as intended, so no reason to paste it here when it is all wrong

Comment: You're less likely to get help if you have not shown that you have made any effort yourself. Non-working code is quite possibly remediable - that's sort of what people do here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim writeRow As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor, ColorRow As Long
    Dim rColored As Range
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim temprow As Long
    Dim lnRow As Long, cellvalueTemp As String
    Dim WS As Workbook

    lColor = RGB(255, 153, 204)
    Set rColored = Nothing

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet2"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet3"

    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Tag"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Terminal"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "CollectiveGroupName"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = "LogicalGroupName"

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
writeRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:A" & lastRow)


For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Interior.Color = lColor Then
        ColorRow = cel.Row + 1

            For i = ColorRow To lastRow
                For j = 20 To 100 'Needs to be adjusted, possibily find the last colum and first
               If Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value = "X" Then
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & writeRow).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & writeRow).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i - 7 - (i - ColorRow), j).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & writeRow).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i - 6 - (i - ColorRow), j).Value
                    writeRow = writeRow + 1
                    Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                End If
                'Ikke gjør noe
                Next j
            Next i

            If rColored Is Nothing Then

            Else
            'Ikke gjør noe
            End If

        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```